# How can we set "Return-Path" in a mail when we use "Mail::Sendmail" module to send mail?

Tags: perl, email, sendmail, perl-module

How can we set "Return-Path" in a mail when we use "Mail::Sendmail" module to send mail?

I want to send an email with a from address as `email_id@gmail.com` to `sender_to@gmail.com` from my own server. For example it should be www.example.com

I want to add the `Return-path` for that email as `example@example.com`. I had try many was but failed to set it properly.

The code is as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
use Mail::Sendmail;

%mail = (
    To => $email,
    From=>  $user_email,
    subject=> $subject,
    'X-Mailer'=> "example.com Campaign Sharing Software",
);
$default_email                  = qq{example@example.com};
$mail{'Reply-To'}               = $user_email;
$mail{'content-type'}           = "text/html"; 
$mail{Smtp}                     = $GLOB{settings}{SMTPSERVER_BULK};
$mail{'Message : '}             = $mail_content;
if(sendmail  %mail)
{
       print qq{mail sent successfully};
}
```

I had set `$mail{'Return-Path'} = $default_email;`. But the Return-Path I found in the gmail when click on **Show Original** is **`Return-Path : from_email_id`**.

Actually I want it as **`Return-Path : $default_email`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mail::Sendmail - setting envelope sender

From [the documentation for Mail::Sendmail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail%3a%3aSendmail):

> If you wish to use an envelope sender address different than the From: address, set `$mail{Sender}` in your `%mail` hash

Most mail servers (MTAs) copy envelope sender to `Return-Path:` header.